# Testing Delegate Method with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In the class like the below the only tests required around `doActionOne()` and `doActionTwo()` are to ensure that they delegate to `doAction()` with the correct parameters.

As the delegate `doAction(String a, int b, boolean c)` method requires a lot of set-up then any solution should prevent the real method being called.

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

    public void doActionOne(String a, int b) {
        doAction(a, b, true);
    }

    public void doActionTwo(String a, int b) {
        doAction(a, b, false);
    }

    public void doAction(String a, int b, boolean c) {
        //already tested
    }
}
```

Such a test would seem to require some kind of partial mock or spy however I am unable to get this correct.

The test should look something like the below although this approach doesn't work.

```
@Test
public void testDoActionOne(){
    ClassUnderTest cut = Mockito.mock(ClassUnderTest.class);

    //call the real method
    when(cut.doActionOne("A1", 1)).thenCallRealMethod();

    //test delegate called with correct params
    verify(cut, times(1)).doAction("A1", 1, true); //fails wanted but not invoked
}
```

Not sure if I need something like:

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#delegatesTo(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of two ways to do this. One means creating an anonymous inner class in which you override the method you don't want to test. This does not involve any Mockito magic. The other means using a Mockito Spy object, this is a proxy to a real instance, allowing you to specify stubbed behavior for some methods, and let the other methods fall through to the real instance.

Method 1, using an anonymous inner class:

```
public class MyTest {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private boolean c;

    private ClassUnderTest instance = new ClassUnderTest() {
        @Override
        public void doAction(String a, int b, boolean c) {
            MyTest.this.a = a; 
            MyTest.this.b = b;
            MyTest.this.c = c;
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        // SETUP
        String expectedA = "test value A";
        String expectedB = "test value B";
        boolean expectedC = true;

        // CALL
        instance.doActionOne(expectedA, expectedB);

        // VERIFY
        assertEquals(expectedA, a);
        assertEquals(expectedB, b);
        assertEquals(expectedC , c);
    }
```

Method 2, using Mockito spy object:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Spy
    private ClassUnderTest instance;

    public void test() {
        // SETUP
        String expectedA = "test value A";
        String expectedB = "test value B";
        boolean expectedC = true;
        doNothing().when(instance).doAction(expectedA , expectedB, expectedC);

        // CALL
        instance.doActionOne(expectedA, expectedB);

        // VERIFY
        verify(instance, times(1)).doAction(expectedA , expectedB, expectedC);
    }
```

Because a spy is a Mockito controlled proxy you can also verify if methods were called on a spy, which is what you need here. You could also specify a stubbed return value for doAction (if it wasn't a void method):

```
        // SETUP
        doReturn("stubbed value").when(instance).doAction(expectedA , expectedB, expectedC);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had considered using the non-Mockito approach but using your Mockito based example works fine. The key part for me was to stub the return value so the real delegate method did not execute as that was causing issues. My real code did return something from these methods so using doReturn() was fine. For the sample question I believe the delegate method could be stubbed using doNothing() rather than doReturn() so might be worth adding that to the answer.

Comment: You are right, I added the 'doNothing()' stub to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It goes like this:

```
when(object.getFieldValue(attribute)).thenReturn(NESTED_ID);
verify(object, times(1)).getFieldValue(eq(attribute));
```